Das habe ich der Polizei so oft gesagt
I have heard the following sentence in the 5th episode of the TV series "Lauchhammer - Tod in der Lausitz":

Das habe ich der Polizei so oft gesagt

Context: A girl disappeared 10 years ago and has been recently found dead by the police. The mother says the sentence above to a detective talking to her.
"oft" means "often", but that does not make sense in this sentence because the mother said it many times to the police 10 years ago when the girl disappeared. She didn't say it in the last years because the police had forgotten about the case, so it didn't happen often. Does "oft" mean "many times" in this context? Is it more usual than "viele Male" and "mehrmals" ?

I don't understand your question. Is there a difference in the meaning between "often" and "many times" in English? Doesn't this mean exactly the same? What is the difference between these two versions: 1. "I've told that so often!" and 2. "I've told that so many times!" Maybe #1 is less idiomatic in English, but that's not the point. The point is the meaning. In German "Das habe ich schon so oft gesagt!" and "Das habe ich schon viele Male gesagt!" mean about the same, but the second version is not idiomatic German, although it's correct.

@HubertSchölnast Yes, there is a small difference between multiplicity and periodicity. Also, "often" in English is used for (past, present or future) habits. If someone said something 100 times in a single hour, that doesn't mean it occurred regularly in the past as a whole. For instance, "often" would be used in "my mom used to ask me to take the trash out" (frequently in the whole time we lived together) and not in "my mom asked me to take the trash out many times yesterday".

The "so oft" is a comparison where the counter compared with is not explicitly mentioned. In almost all cases  of "so oft" the actual number of occurrences is dropped/omitted. The full (rare) expression might say "...so oft gesagt, dass ich schon aufgehört habe zu zählen.." or "..so oft gesagt dass ich mich gar nicht mehr daran erinnern kann."


Das habe ich der Polizei so oft gesagt

The emphasis is on "so":

I have told them that so often

"... that I have lost count" or something such. Perhaps they have repeatedly questioned her and she told them the same story over and over. Yes, it implies "viele Male", but it also has a connotation of "I'm fed up with it."

If that was directly translated to English, it would still make sense with 'often' implying habitual repetition - "I told the police that so often", ie. 'I told the police that regularly over a period of time in the past, but I stopped doing it a while ago'.
This could have been the case if the person followed up with the police daily/weekly/etc for a year until it became obvious that they were not going to do or find anything, at which point she gave up.

I think "I used to tell the police that so often" would be the most usual construction for past habits in English.
